# relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, opencv, glibc

Following the indications found here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html I'm trying to compile, build and install OpenCV 4.8 in Ubuntu 23.10

I compiled:

```
raphy@raohy:~/builddir-opencv$ cmake CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC" 
-DOPENCV_FORCE_VTK=TRUE -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-
4.x/modules ../opencv-4.x
```

without any errors

But, in building phase, I get this error:

```
[ 94%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_sfm.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a(gflags_completions.cc.o): warning: relocation against `_ZN3fLS25FLAGS_tab_completion_wordB5cxx11E' in read-only section `.text.startup'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a(gflags.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [modules/sfm/CMakeFiles/opencv_sfm.dir/build.make:242: lib/libopencv_sfm.so.4.9.0] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7756: modules/sfm/CMakeFiles/opencv_sfm.dir/all] Error 2
```

How to make it work?

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/usr-bin-ld-usr-local-lib-libgflags-a-gflags-cc-o-relocation-r-x86-64-pc32-against-symbol-stderr-glibc-2-2-5-can-not-be-used-when-making-a-shared-object-recompile-with-fpic/16044

Comment: do you need `sfm`? if not, disable it and move on. browse values listed by cmake-gui to find the option.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue thanks to this github's discussion suggestion:

https://github.com/google/glog/issues/680#issuecomment-1270588709

I first compiled and built `gflags` library (https://github.com/gflags/gflags) with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` flag: `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -B build`  . Then compiled and built `glogs` library (https://github.com/google/glog). The building phase of `opencv-4.x` library went then smoothly fine